# Save to mongoDB after receiving from RabbitMQ

Tags: mongodb, rabbitmq, nestjs

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppController (?). Please make sure that the argument MongoRepository at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

```
Potential solutions:
- If MongoRepository is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If MongoRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing MongoRepository */ ]
  })
```

Am I wrong in trying to use mongo here like this

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly db: MongoRepository<Product>) { }
  @EventPattern( "abc" )
  async handleMessagePrinted(data: Record<string, unknown>) {
   this.db.save(product);
  }


}
```

My goal is to just be able to sabe "Product"